# Change eventbridge cron rule name in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I have a lambda that I trigger with an `EventBridge`.

I have `allowed_triggers` in my `lambda_function`:

```
  allowed_triggers = {
    "RunDaily" = {
      principal  = "events.amazonaws.com"
      source_arn = module.eventbridge.eventbridge_rule_arns["crons"]
    }
  }
```

And I have an `eventbridge` module:

```
module "eventbridge" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/aws"
  version = "1.14.0"

  create_bus   = false
  create_role  = false
  create_rules = true

  rules = {
    crons = {
      description         = "deafault"
      schedule_expression = "rate(1 day)"
    }
  }

  targets = {
    crons = [
      {
        arn   = module.lambda_function.lambda_function_arn
        input = jsonencode({ "job" : "crons" })
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, this works great, as the rule is created and attached properly.

[image]

But when I want to change the name of the rule along with its description, terraform pickups only the description change:

```
module "eventbridge" {
  ...
  rules = {
    crons = {
      description         = "My custom cron rule"
      schedule_expression = "rate(1 day)"
    }
  }

  targets = {
    crons = [
      {
        name  = "my-custom-cron-rule-name"
        arn   = module.lambda_function.lambda_function_arn
        input = jsonencode({ "job" : "crons" })
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Plan:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.eventbridge.aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.this["crons"] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "this" {
      ~ description         = "deafault" -> "My custom cron rule"
        id                  = "crons-rule"
        name                = "crons-rule"
        tags                = {
            "Name" = "crons-rule"
        }
        # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

---

**Question:** *How do I change the `name` attribute for an `eventbridge` rule?*

Comment: Well, the name is probably coming from the module. Unless it provides an input variable for which you can set a name, it will remain with the same name. Can you add the module code as well?

Comment: That's all the code there is for the `eventbridge` module. I'm using [terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/aws/latest#eventbridge-with-schedule-rule-and-lambda-target)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the module definition [1], the `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` name is derived from value of the **key** of the `rules` block, i.e.:

```
  rules = {
    crons = {
      description         = "My custom cron rule"
      schedule_expression = "rate(1 day)"
    }
  }
```

Based on the lines from the GitHub repo, the name is formed with:

```
locals {
  eventbridge_rules = flatten([
    for index, rule in var.rules :
    merge(rule, {
      "name" = index
      "Name" = "${replace(index, "_", "-")}-rule"
    })
  ])
... # rest of locals goes here
}
```

If you take a look at your definition and this part of code, you can see that the name will be `crons-rule`, which is visible in both the `name` and `tags.Name` arguments:

```
        name                = "crons-rule"
        tags                = {
            "Name" = "crons-rule"
        }
```

So in order to change the name of the rule, you would have to change the key of the rules block, i.e.:

```
  rules = {
    very-nice-new-crons = { # <----- here is where the change should be made
      description         = "My custom cron rule"
      schedule_expression = "rate(1 day)"
    }
  }
```

You can verify this by looking at [2]:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "this" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.eventbridge_rules : v.name => v if var.create && var.create_rules }

  name        = each.value.Name
  ...

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name = each.value.Name
  })
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out, there are two more changes that need to be made after the name is changed:

1. The `allowed_triggers` of the Lambda function should now use the new key to reference the event rule that is allowed to trigger it. It has to be changed from

```
source_arn = module.eventbridge.eventbridge_rule_arns["crons"]
```

to

```
source_arn = module.eventbridge.eventbridge_rule_arns["very-nice-new-crons"]
```

2. The same name change has to be used in the `targets` block as well, i.e., the `crons` key in the `targets` has to be replaced with the same key name as in the `rules` block:

```
  targets = {
    very-nice-new-crons = [
      {
        name  = "my-custom-cron-rule-name"
        arn   = module.lambda_function.lambda_function_arn
        input = jsonencode({ "job" : "crons" })
      }
    ]
  }
```

---

[1] https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eventbridge/blob/master/main.tf#L2-L6

[2] https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eventbridge/blob/master/main.tf#L44

Comment: Good point to look at the source code. You pushed me in the right direction. Changing `crons` to `very-nice-new-crons` makes sense, but you forgot to mention the change has to propagate to `targets` and `allowed_triggers -> source_arn = ...["very-nice-new-crons"]`.

Comment: Ha, well, you did ask how to change the name. :) I'll update the answer. :)

Comment: Good job on that one!